# Apply multiple rotations to ARKit SCNNode

Tags: swift, scenekit, linear-algebra, arkit

I'm working with an AR app that uses Apple's Focus Square to guide user interaction on both vertical and horizontal surfaces. However, it's only designed to work on horizontal surfaces. I have modified the method that updates the square's rotation to account for vertical surfaces as well. However, using the method that they used only one rotation can be performed at a time, whereas in order to have the square positioned properly on a horizontal surface I need to have two rotations performed (one to apply the original yaw correction, and one to pitch the square vertically).

The relevant code is below, but the specific changes I made are only at the beginning and end.

```
// MARK: - Appearence

func update(for position: float3, planeAnchor: ARPlaneAnchor?, camera: ARCamera?) {
    lastPosition = position

    let thisAlignment = planeAnchor?.alignment ?? .horizontal
    if thisAlignment != lastAlignment {
        lastAlignment = thisAlignment
        print("alignmentChanged")
        recentFocusSquarePositions = []
    }

    if let anchor = planeAnchor {
        close(flash: !anchorsOfVisitedPlanes.contains(anchor))
        lastPositionOnPlane = position
        anchorsOfVisitedPlanes.insert(anchor)
    } else {
        open()
    }
    updateTransform(for: position, alignment: thisAlignment, camera: camera)
}

private func updateTransform(for position: float3, alignment: ARPlaneAnchor.Alignment, camera: ARCamera?) {
    // add to list of recent positions
    recentFocusSquarePositions.append(position)

    // remove anything older than the last 8
    recentFocusSquarePositions.keepLast(8)

    // move to average of recent positions to avoid jitter
    if let average = recentFocusSquarePositions.average {
        self.simdPosition = average
        self.setUniformScale(scaleBasedOnDistance(camera: camera))
    }

    // Correct y rotation of camera square
    if let camera = camera {
        let tilt = abs(camera.eulerAngles.x)
        let threshold1: Float = .pi / 2 * 0.65
        let threshold2: Float = .pi / 2 * 0.75
        let yaw = atan2f(camera.transform.columns.0.x, camera.transform.columns.1.x)
        var angle: Float = 0

        switch tilt {
        case 0..<threshold1:
            angle = camera.eulerAngles.y
        case threshold1..<threshold2:
            let relativeInRange = abs((tilt - threshold1) / (threshold2 - threshold1))
            let normalizedY = normalize(camera.eulerAngles.y, forMinimalRotationTo: yaw)
            angle = normalizedY * (1 - relativeInRange) + yaw * relativeInRange
        default:
            angle = yaw
        }

        if alignment == .vertical{
            self.rotation = SCNVector4(0, 1, 1, Float.pi)
        } else {
            self.rotation = SCNVector4(0, 1, 0, angle)
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to have both the rotations in the control statement at the end performed on the object. If the `else` statement is removed, only that rotation is applied and the square remains horizontal. I have tried making both modifications to the transform directly using `SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(_:_:_:_:)` but this caused the square to spin endlessly and position itself incorrectly. I also tried adjusting the node's `Pivot` but this resulted in no visible changes to the object.

Comment: Update: After revisiting the Pivot property, ensuring it is updated before the rotation property, and playing around with the applied transform, I got it to work with this conditional:
 `if alignment == .vertical { self.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float.pi, 0, 1, 1) } else { self.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(0, 0, 0, 0) }`

However the focus square now yaws against the vertical plane rather than along it...

Comment: Update: Integrated the focus square from [this Apple sample project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/handling_3d_interaction_and_ui_controls_in_augmented_reality), which works properly on vertical surfaces. I would still like to know how to make multiple rotations, though, for my own edification and that of the community. If no answers are posted, I'll see if I can reverse engineer the Apple code from above to see how they solved the issue.